# Does TextView's onDraw supports graphical drawing?

Tags: android

I tried to subclass a textView and add a bitmap to it. It does not work.
Using the same subclass, i experiment by drawing a line. It still does not work.
I tried to draw text. It works.

When I changed the base class from textView to View. Everything works.

I'm wondering if textView does not support drawing of anything else except text?
Can someone show an example of working code on how to draw a line using drawLine() in onDraw() of a view with a base class of textView?

```
package com.main.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Display extends TextView{

    Paint p;

    public Display (Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
    }

    public Display (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
       p = new Paint();
       p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       canvas.drawLine(0, 0, this.getMeasuredWidth(), this.getMeasuredHeight(), p);
    }
}
```

main activity's code
    package com.main.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity {
    Display input;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initcomponents();
    }


    private void initcomponents()
    {
        input = (Display)findViewById(R.id.rateInput);
    }
}
```

If I change it from TextView to View. It works.

```
package com.main.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Display extends View{

    Paint p;

    public Display (Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
    }

    public Display (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
       p = new Paint();
       p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       canvas.drawLine(0, 0, this.getMeasuredWidth(), this.getMeasuredHeight(), p);
    }
}
```

main activity's code
    package com.main.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

public class main extends Activity {
    View input;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initcomponents();
    }


    private void initcomponents()
    {
        input = (View)findViewById(R.id.rateInput);
    }
}
```

ok this system don't allow me to post pic for now. So i cannot show you the results from the 2nd code.

Comment: Yes it does. Show your code...

Comment: My first guess would be that it should work. Why you shouldnt be able to draw on the Canvas of a TextView?

Answer (score 1):

ok I found the reason why drawline does not work already.

When i remove this line in the manifest XML. the line can be drawn.

android:inputType="numberDecimal"

But why...?

Answer (score 0):

[The Notepad example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) draws lines on an EditText which is a subclass of TextView, so it must be possible. I'm not sure why your code doesn't work though, but see `LinedTextEdit` in [this file](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NoteEditor.html).